# Javascript On/Off Button

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I hope you are doing fine under these circumstances. I am creating a webpage where there's a button which when clicked inverts the color of the webpage. I've very new to programming so I'm still trying to figure out everything. I have the following CSS code which inverts the colors -

```
body {
filter: invert(0.85);
}
```

However, I wish to add a button which when clicked inverts the colors and when clicked again, brings them back to normal (ie inverts them again). Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To implement this behavior you're going to need a bit of JavaScript.

First, let's give a CSS class to the code that inverts the colors:

```css
body.colors-inverted {
  filter: invert(0.85);
}
```

Then, let's add a button to our HTML:

```html
<button id='invert-colors'>Invert colors</button>
```

And make the button toggle the `colors-inverted` class on the `body` element:

```js
// find the button on the page
let btn = document.querySelector('#invert-colors');

// when clicking the button, toggle the class on <body>
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.body.classList.toggle('colors-inverted');
});
```

(Note: the script above needs to be added in a `<script>` element somewhere in the HTML, anywhere *after* the `<button>` element).

Here's a running example, with two ways of doing it:

- Based on a button (using the `click` event)
- Based on a checkbox (using the `change` event and the `e.target.checked` state)

```js
let btn = document.querySelector('#invert-colors-button');
btn.addEventListener('click', function toggle() {
  document.body.classList.toggle('colors-inverted');
});

let cb = document.querySelector('#invert-colors-checkbox');
cb.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
   document.body.classList.toggle('colors-inverted', e.target.checked);
});
```

```css
body.colors-inverted {
  filter: invert(0.85);
}
```

```html
<h1>Welcome to my website!</h1>
<button id='invert-colors-button'>Invert colors</button>

<input type='checkbox' id='invert-colors-checkbox'/> 
<label for='invert-colors-checkbox'>Invert colors</label>
```

Comment: Thank you for your input! I was curious, is there a way to have it for a checkbox? I've actually created a sliding button which is just a checkbox on the inside. How can I use use that instead of a hardcore html button, if you know what I mean? Thank for the help tho!

Comment: Sure. I've updated the snippet to include an example where you take the checked/unchecked status of a checkbox and apply the class based on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class in the body for toggle the dark mode

```js
const body = document.querySelector('body');
const button = document.querySelector('.toggleDarkmode');

button.addEventListener('change', ()=> {
  body.classList.toggle('active')
})
```

```css
body.active {
  filter: invert(0.85);
}

.wrapper {
  background: white;
  height: 100vh;
width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <input type="checkbox" class="toggleDarkmode">Dark MODE!
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your input! I was curious, is there a way to have it for a checkbox? I've actually created a sliding button which is just a checkbox on the inside. How can I use use that instead of a hardcore html button, if you know what I mean? Thank for the help tho!

Comment: @Noor I've changed the snippet, hope that helps! ;)

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to do this, but it really depends on what the rest of your project looks like. If you're using a framework such as `React` for javascript or `Django` for Python, I'd suggest looking for a theming library like [`styled-components`](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components) to help you. If you're using plain CSS and Javascript, which is what I'm assuming, you can make a simple javascript toggle function which toggles a class on the main `<html>` element. Then you can create your styles accordingly.

sample:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      html body {
        background-color: white;
        color: black;
      }
      html.inverted body{
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Hello!</h2>
    <p>this is a paragraph</p>
    <button onclick="toggleTheme()">click me to toggle theme</button>
    <script>
      function toggleTheme() {
        let body = document.documentElement;
        let toggleClass = 'inverted';

        if (body.classList.contains(toggleClass)) {
          body.classList.remove(toggleClass);
        } else {
          body.classList.add(toggleClass);
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In this example, all it does is toggle the background color and text color, but you can make it affect any class or element by adding the toggleClass modifier in front of it (e.g. `html.inverted h1.myHeading`).

Comment: Hi! Thanks you so much for this. I understand it might be far fetched of me to think about something like this as a newbie but do you think it's possible to maybe have a little transition period as the page is inverting its color from white to black?

Comment: Yes! Try looking into the CSS `transition` property: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp
So if you wanted to transition the background from white to black in 0.3 seconds, you could add the style `transition: background-color 0.3s;`.